Copmparing the height of two div's
I have a list of object testList and would like to compare the offsetHeight difference betweeninnerRef and outerRef.
I am not sure why the outerRef offsetHeight value is always smaller than innerRef offsetHeight value no matter how long the length of {item.remark}is
So far this is my code:
<div ref={outerRef}>
  {testList.map(({item, index}) =>
      return (
         <div>
            <span ref={this.innerRef}
                {item.remark} 
            </span> 
         </div>  
             ));
  }
</div>

In the componentDidUpdate, I compared the two ref’s offsetHeight
if(this.outerRef.current.offsetHeight < this.innerRef.current.offsetHeight){
   this.setState({overflow: true});
else{
  this.setState({overflow: false});
}


The approach you take depends on your intention.
If you're trying to compare the height of the outer container with the height of an individual list item as the inner element, then you can keep your existing logic. In this case, the overflow state will be set to true once any single list item's height exceeds the height of the outer container:
    function App() {
  const testList = [
    // list items
  ];

  const outerRef = useRef(null);
  const innerRef = useRef(null);
  const [overflow, setOverflow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (outerRef.current && innerRef.current) {
      if (outerRef.current.offsetHeight < innerRef.current.offsetHeight) setOverflow(true);
      else setOverflow(false);
      console.log(`Overflow: ${overflow}`); 
    }
  }, [testList]); 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className='App-header'>
      <div ref={outerRef} style={{ maxHeight: '100px', backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
          {testList.map(({ item, remark }, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <span ref={innerRef}>
                {remark}
              </span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

On the other hand, if your goal is to determine if the total height of all list items exceeds the height of the outer container, you'll need to change your logic. Instead of comparing with a single inner element, calculate the total height of all inner elements and then compare it with the outer container's height:
const outerRef = useRef(null);
  const [overflow, setOverflow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (outerRef.current) {
      const totalInnerHeight = Array.from(outerRef.current.children).reduce((totalHeight, child) => {
        return totalHeight + child.offsetHeight;
      }, 0);
      if (outerRef.current.offsetHeight < totalInnerHeight) setOverflow(true);
      else setOverflow(false);
    }
  }, [testList]);
  console.log(`Overflow: ${overflow}`);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className='App-header'>
        <div ref={outerRef} style={{ maxHeight: '100px', backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
          {testList.map(({ item, remark }, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <span>
                {remark}
              </span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );

